# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized sharepoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

Here is my scenario:-

I have my Sharepoint server hosted on **Domain A** and I have my machine on **Domain B**.
There is **not any trust** between **Domain A and Domain B**.

I am trying to access the Sharepoint Document library from my machine to Sharepoint server which is on Domain A.

Now when i used this code:-

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);
clientContext.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username,password,domain);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I got the following error:-

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

I want to know (Correct me if i am wrong) is it possible to access sharepoint document library accross the domain without having trust between each other and the only solution i think is my machine should be on the Domain A.

**Update**

I transfered my machine on Domain A that is on that domain where sharepoint server is installed. Still same error getting at clientContext.ExecuteQuery();. I dont know why pelase help.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of authentication you are employing within the target web application on **Domain A**? And does the SharePoint server on **Domain A** know who `username` is? You may also want to see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/does-managed-client-object-model-work-for-cross-domain

Comment: **NTLM windows authentication** and our sharepoint server is on Domain A and yes the credentials which i am using are already exist on Doamin A means on Sharepoint server

Answer (score 1):

Can you access the SharePoint library with your browser when you use the user? If so then this could be doublehop issue;

> "The double-hop problem will usually only be an issue to those of you
>   who write some sort of web-based code (a web application or web
>   service) that uses impersonation."

I´m probably the least capable person to work with code but I would like you to try out the browser with the user and see what happens. 
**EDIT:**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

Comment: Hi Funi! Can you please clarify in your post where that quote is from? :)

Comment: Fixed. Noted for future posts. :)

Comment: Great! It is easy to forget, but it is nice to give people credit for their contributions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can and its called cross domain access that you would need to setup on the server, this is a link to another question with the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780886/cross-domain-access-in-sharepoint-2010

hope it helps :)

Comment: I transfered my machine to same domain but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the credentials you're passing match the destination farm's authentication mechanism - classic/claims (assuming this is 2010).

Also try using the Secure Store Service Application to host your connection credential settings.